# CMake CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS Can't Export inline method

Tags: c++, c, cmake

This is my .h file code:

```
class dtTileCache
{
     inline int getTileCount() const { return m_params.maxTiles; }
}
```

I have marked `CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS` as `True`
In addition to the inline function can not be exported, everything is normal, 
I wanted to set what parameters can be exported inline function?

Comment: I do not see the need for the inline function export. Any code that depends on your code will have this function definition after inclusion of the header file with your class. If I miss something, then please point me on this.

Comment: @InnokentiyAlaytsev: Exported version will be used if one gets **reference** to the inline function (inline function's member in given case).

Comment: Then probably it is better to export all required symbols manually with `__declspec(dllexport)`. As far as I know, it is the most reliable way of exporting symbols under Windows.